# Logout from Keycloak is not working properly

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

when i call below code, it will go to if statement i.e. keycloak.authenticated. Aftert that keycloak.logout(), neither alert Success nor Fail will not display.

```
if(keycloak.authenticated) {   
  keycloak.logout().then((success) => {
        alert("Success")
    }).catch((error) => {
           alert("Fail")
    });
}
```

let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to pass also logout options, e.g. `{ redirectUri : "<post logout url>" }`

Comment: Here is my code.
`code`
 if(keycloak.authenticated) {   
      const url=encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/logout");
     const backurl="https://{KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}//protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri="+url;
      keycloak.logout(backurl).then((success) => {
            alert("Success")
        }).catch((error) => {
               alert("Fail")
        });
`code`
Still its not working. I supect that my keycloak url is https but my redirect url is http. This might be the issue.